# Cordova InAppBrowser displays white screen

Tags: android, ios, asp.net-mvc, cordova, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple app that I've created which basically authenticates with an Api before loading a URL in an InAppBrowser:

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(
        "http://www.example.com",
        '_self',
        'location=no');
```

The site is an `MVC4` basic site.

The first page loads perfectly fine but when clicking a link to move to another page within the site i.e. `http://www.example.com/Login` then a white page is displayed.  Does InAppBrowser not support the ability to navigate through a site?  Is there an alternative?

Comment: have you tried navigation by loading another site other than yours? e.g."http://www.bbc.co.uk/"

Comment: Figured it out, It was X-Header options

Comment: post it as an answer to help others as well